# Unrecognized command line option '-Zi'

Tags: c, makefile

I get missing this error in the makefile as stated:The error is the Zi command used in CFLAGS and i am sure the error will occur for other CFLAGS as well

```
# Makefile to create LeX with Microsoft C 7.0 and nmake

OBJ1 = lex.obj squash.obj minimize.obj dfa.obj input.obj nfa.obj
OBJ2 = print.obj printnfa.obj signon.obj terp.obj
D    =

# Add -DMAP_MALLOC to CFLAGS if you wan't malloc checking

CFLAGS  = -Zi -Ox     -c -AC $(D)
CFLAGS2 = -Zi -Ox -Oa -c -AC $(D)

.c.obj :
    cc $(CFLAGS) $*.c

#--------------------------------------------------------------

lex.exe :  $(OBJ1) $(OBJ2)
    link /CP:1 /NOI /CO @<<$(OBJ1) +$(OBJ2) lex nul \lib\compc.lib nul <<

#--------------------------------------------------------------

final :  $(OBJ1) $(OBJ2)
    link /CP:1 /NOI @<< $(OBJ1) + $(OBJ2) lex nul \lib\compc.lib nul <<

#--------------------------------------------------------------
# Test LeX by building a llama lexical analyzer. There's a test main()
# in parser.lex that's created if MAIN is defined.

lexyy.exe : lexyy.obj
    link /CP:1 /NOI /CO @<< lexyy.obj lexyy lexyy \lib\l.lib nul <<

lexyy.obj : lexyy.c
    cc -Zi -Os -c -DMAIN lexyy.c

lexyy.c : /src/compiler/parser/parser.lex
    lex -v /src/compiler/parser/parser.lex

#--------------------------------------------------------------

all : nfa.exe terp.exe dfa.exe lex.exe

#--------------------------------------------------------------

dfa.exe :   dfa.c nfa.obj terp.obj printnfa.obj print.obj
            cc $(CFLAGS) -DDEBUG -DMAIN dfa.c
            cc dfa.obj nfa.obj terp.obj printnfa.obj print.obj \
                            -link \lib\compc.lib /CO
            touch dfa.c

terp.exe :  terp.c nfa.obj printnfa.obj
            cc $(CFLAGS) -DMAIN terp.c
            cc terp.obj nfa.obj printnfa.obj -link \lib\compc.lib /CO
            touch terp.c

nfa.exe :   nfa.c printnfa.obj
            cc $(CFLAGS) -DDEBUG -DMAIN nfa.c
            cc nfa.obj printnfa.obj -link \lib\compc.lib /CO
            touch nfa.c

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------

input.obj : input.c               globals.h
lex.obj :   lex.c       dfa.h  nfa.h  globals.h
minimize.obj :  minimize.c  dfa.h         globals.h
nfa.obj :   nfa.c              nfa.h  globals.h
print.obj : print.c     dfa.h  nfa.h  globals.h
printnfa.obj :  printnfa.c         nfa.h
signon.obj :    signon.c
squash.obj :    squash.c    dfa.h         globals.h

dfa.obj :   dfa.c       dfa.h         globals.h
            cc $(CFLAGS2)   dfa.c

terp.obj :  terp.c      nfa.h         globals.h
            cc $(CFLAGS2)   terp.c
```

The error message is:

```
 cc -Zi -Ox -Oa -c -AC  dfa.c
 cc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-Zi’
 make: *** [dfa.obj] Error 1
```

Comment: Please post the error message ecactly like you see it.

Comment: Does the Microsoft compiler recognize options starting with `-` or do they have to start with `/`?  So `/Zi` etc?

Comment: What is `cc` in your case? What this flag should do?